# Didn't get the current userid using wordpress api call

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress user is login in the chrome browser and call custom  api created using 
wp-json plugin from the chrome extension but in the api file i didn't get the current user id using the  get_current_user_id().

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Install  and activate [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://pt.wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) plugin, also install  [WP REST API](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API) plugin 
 **2.** Now you can run any wordpress default api from mobile app or any other source or by postman. for example hit this url from your app or by postman. https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts 
 **3.** By app or by postman, When you will login with valid details (using rest api) you will get back a token. To login and get token, run the following url by postman or by app
 https://example.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token
 
 **4.** By this way you will get a token as shown in picture
[image: postman and jwt authentication]

Now use this token to get logged in user details, for example
**5.** make function in function.php

```
function checkloggedinuser()
{
$currentuserid_fromjwt = get_current_user_id();
print_r($currentuserid_fromjwt);
exit;
}

 add_action('rest_api_init', function ()
{
  register_rest_route( 'testone', 'loggedinuser',array(
  'methods' => 'POST',
  'callback' => 'checkloggedinuser'
  ));
});
```

**6.** Now again run this new url in postman or in app to get logged in user details.
https://example.com/wp-json/testone/loggedinuser
(replace example.com with your url)
if you have any question, you can comment here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all need to check wp-load.php call or not, where it a function of API.

Outside of WordPress functions is not work so need to call **wp-load.php** (this file exist wp root directory)then this **get_current_user_id()** is work correct.

Comment: the api is created using a plugin. I think wp-load.php is loaded